Is there a way to catch all members being added to a group in batches?
I wrote a python class to add members to a Google group in batches of 100 to a Google group. The problem is that the number of members in the new_members variable does not match the number of members being added to the group, it is much less. From what I can tell, not all successful calls to members().insert() are reported back to my callback function. Anyone have a better way, other than inserting one-by-one?
class MemberService:
    def __init__(self, creds):
        self.service = build("admin", "directory_v1", credentials=creds)
        self.__has_error = False


    def __insert_chunk(self, group_key: str, chunk: list[Member]):
        new_members: list[Member] = []
        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

        def insert_member_callback(request_id, response, exception):
            if exception is not None:
                status_code = exception.status_code

                if status_code in (403, 429):
                    raise exception
                elif status_code == 409:
                    logger.warning(f"{request_id}: Warning inserting member to group: {group_key}: {exception}")
                else:
                    self.__has_error = True
                    logger.error(f"{request_id}: Exception inserting member to group: {group_key}: {exception}")
            else:
                new_member = Member(**response)
                new_members.append(new_member)
                logger.info(f"{request_id}: Inserted member: {new_member.email} into group: {group_key}")
        
        @retry(tries=5, delay=1, backoff=2)
        def execute_insert_chunk():
            batch: BatchHttpRequest = self.service.new_batch_http_request(callback=insert_member_callback)
            for member in chunk:
                if member not in new_members:
                    batch.add(self.service.members().insert(groupKey=group_key, body=member.to_dict()))

            batch.execute()

        execute_insert_chunk()
        logger.info(f"__insert_chunk: Inserted {len(new_members)}/{len(chunk)}  members")
        return new_members

    def insert_members(self, group_key: str, members: list[Member]) -> list[Member]:
        new_members: list[Member] = []
        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

        if not isinstance(members, list) or not all(isinstance(m, Member) for m in members):
            raise TypeError("Object, members, is not an instance of list[Member]")

        # Partition the list of members into chunks of size 100
        member_chunks = [members[i:i+100] for i in range(0, len(members), 100)]

        # Insert each chunk of members
        for chunk in member_chunks:
            new_members_chunk = self.__insert_chunk(group_key, chunk)
            new_members.extend(new_members_chunk)

        logger.info(f"Inserted {len(new_members)} members to group: {group_key}")
        return new_members`

I have over 1000 members to insert and only 600 or 700 are reported. Initial chunks are reporting 100 inserts (my chunk size), but others are reporting 3-50 inserts. Running 'grep __insert_chunk groupsmemberautomation.log' returns the following after inserting 1348 members to my test group.
INFO: __insert_chunk: Inserted 100/100 members
INFO: __insert_chunk: Inserted 52/100 members
INFO: __insert_chunk: Inserted 49/100 members
INFO: __insert_chunk: Inserted 100/100 members
INFO: __insert_chunk: Inserted 31/100 members
INFO: __insert_chunk: Inserted 100/100 members
INFO: __insert_chunk: Inserted 52/100 members
INFO: __insert_chunk: Inserted 49/100 members
INFO: __insert_chunk: Inserted 54/100 members
INFO: __insert_chunk: Inserted 50/100 members
INFO: __insert_chunk: Inserted 48/100 members
INFO: __insert_chunk: Inserted 57/100 members
INFO: __insert_chunk: Inserted 27/100 members
INFO: __insert_chunk: Inserted 47/48 members

My test group reflects the full 1348 members in the Admin console of my Google tenant.
